# Python regular expression 'findall' is not returning all expressions

Tags: python, regex

I want to find all expressions wrapped with "<" and ">"
For example, in <2><1>, I want <2> and <1> seperately.

```
s = re.findall('<.*>', '<2><1>')
```

gives me only <2><1>, which is different from what I've intended. Can you give me an answer to find all of these expressions ? Thanks much in advance.

Comment: insert input and output correctly in order to be able to help you

Comment: You have a greediness issue. Change to `<.*?>` or `<[^>]*>`.

Comment: [greedy regex expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions)

Comment: Thanks guys ! I've found the solution

Comment: I have another question, I want to remove $$\$$50,000$$ this kind of expressions, and tried """ re.sub("$$\\$$.*?$$", "", text) """, which didn't work out quite well. Substituting \\ with \ didn't work as well. What is the problem ?